# Android adb log - Collecting recent log after application crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, crash-reports, android-logcat

Keywords: android, log, adb

My problem is after long runnning time, my application crashes while resumes. This bug crashes abnormaly, so I cannot collect it at that time.

Right after my application crashes, I want to collect recent log of my application so I can find out the bug. How can I do it?

Any suggestion may help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least to ways to do it:

#### Crashlytics

To collect crash reports, I advise you to use `Crashlytics`. Made by Twitter, easy to maintain and use.
Here you would find more info:

https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary

http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk-android/

It has also an Android Studio & IntelliJ Idea plugins.

#### Firebase Crash Reporting

You can also use introduced by Google new `Fibase` feature called Firebase Crash Reporting. Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/

I've already used the first solution and I'm pretty sure that you would love this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of piotrek1543 is great.

I just add this as an situational option:
After your app crashes, there is a chance that your phone still have that log. If that is the case, you can connect your phone with usb cable then use adb shell to fetch it:

```
adb shell "logcat your.app.package:W -v long | grep E/AndroidRuntime" > android.log
```

`E/AndroidRuntime` is a key filter for android runtime error log, change it as you want. You will get something like:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494): Process: your.app.package, PID: 2494

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494): java.lang.RuntimeException: MainActivity btn_throwException

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at your.app.package.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2494):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

see more here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html